# magento 1.9 onepage checkout stuck on shipping method

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem on my Magento 1.9 site with accessshop theme installed. I am facing while checking out the product the one-page stuck on shipping method. I have used firebug to analyze the ajax request error

```
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 477ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 473ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 486ms]
```

Any suggestions?

Response headers

```
Cache-Controlno-store, no-cache, must-revalidateConnectionKeep-AliveContent-Length0Content-Typetext/html; charset=UTF-8DateSun, 06 Aug 2017 11:15:37 GMTExpiresThu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMTKeep-Alivetimeout=5, max=100Pragmano-cacheServerApache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.4Set-Cookiefrontend=n8402r130lcvu9nih5mc0m77m4; expires=Sun, 06-Aug-2017 12:15:38 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=35.154.241.195; HttpOnlyX-Content-Type-OptionsnosniffX-Frame-OptionsSAMEORIGINX-Powered-ByPHP/7.0.4X-XSS-Protection1; mode=block
```

Response

Empty

Comment: It means that you have an error in JS or wrong response from server. Did you check responses?

Comment: I have added the response headers

Comment: Did you check system.log, exception.log and php error log?

Answer (score 1):

I had this "stuck on shipping method" issue, using a custom theme. I don't have a huge amount of magento experience so it was a bit frustrating.  No PHP errors, no JS errors, checkout-payment-method-load ID was there.

Turns out I needed to include the formkey, which must be something included in a new supee update. My advise to anyone would be (just in case this type of scenario arises in a different situation or future update) check the original files and compare with your active theme.  Originals in this case are located at /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.
Your theme location will obviously vary, but mine was /app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/checkout/onepage

So my **shipping_method.phtml** needed to end with these two lines  (note: formkey!)

```
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
</form>
```

AND my **payment.phtml** needed to have this form key too, here's the snippet

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
         <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

Hope this helps someone save some time!

Comment: I have same problem, but this not solving it. After adding id, there aren't any payment methods.

Answer (score 0):

Open this file `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml` and replace below code:

```
<fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
with (add id to fieldset)

<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```